# “Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection” after update

Tags: update, connection

There was using tor browser 6.5.2 and was'nt problem.
Today it updated to 7.0.1 version and this problem (((

Settings:

ISP block to tor - yes

connection type - obfs4

Local proxy - No

Log:

```
19.06.2017 12:34:09.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19.06.2017 12:34:09.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
19.06.2017 12:34:16.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
19.06.2017 12:34:16.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
19.06.2017 12:34:16.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:34:16.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:34:16.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:34:16.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.13:16815 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:34:16.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
19.06.2017 12:34:16.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
19.06.2017 12:34:16.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:34:16.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:34:16.900 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'dragon' (fresh): $1LXj6eGGMY2YTsF6JQWgr4q8U97D4k3v9Z~dragon at 37.218.245.14 
19.06.2017 12:34:16.900 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We're missing descriptors for some of our primary entry guards 
19.06.2017 12:34:17.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:34:17.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:34:17.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:34:17.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.13:16815 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:34:18.000 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'cymrubridge31' (fresh): $1LXj6eGGMY2YTsF6JQWgr4q8U97D4k3v9Z~cymrubridge31 at 38.229.1.78 
19.06.2017 12:34:18.000 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We're missing descriptors for some of our primary entry guards 
19.06.2017 12:34:18.400 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'cymrubridge33' (fresh): $1LXj6eGGMY2YTsF6JQWgr4q8U97D4k3v9Z~cymrubridge33 at 38.229.33.83 
19.06.2017 12:34:18.400 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We're missing descriptors for some of our primary entry guards 
19.06.2017 12:34:18.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 37.218.240.34:40035 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:35:01.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:35:01.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:35:01.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.99.11.54:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:35:01.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.95.36.142:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:35:01.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:35:01.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.9:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:35:16.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:36:07.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
19.06.2017 12:36:07.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19.06.2017 12:36:07.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
19.06.2017 12:36:07.200 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
19.06.2017 12:36:17.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19.06.2017 12:36:17.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19.06.2017 12:36:17.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19.06.2017 12:36:17.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
19.06.2017 12:36:24.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 2001:470:b381:bfff:216:3eff:fe23:d6c3:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:36:24.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:36:24.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:36:24.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:36:24.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 2001:470:b381:bfff:216:3eff:fe23:d6c3:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:36:24.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:36:24.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:36:25.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 2001:470:b381:bfff:216:3eff:fe23:d6c3:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:36:25.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:36:25.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:36:25.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:36:25.000 [NOTICE] Bridge 'NX01' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (85.17.30.79:443) based on the configured Bridge address. 
19.06.2017 12:36:25.000 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'NX01' (fresh): $1LXj6eGGMY2YTsF6JQWgr4q8U97D4k3v9Z~NX01 at 85.17.30.79 
19.06.2017 12:36:25.000 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We're missing descriptors for some of our primary entry guards 
19.06.2017 12:36:26.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 37.218.240.34:40035 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:36:45.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:4304 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:37:09.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:37:09.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:37:09.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.99.11.54:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:37:09.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.13:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:37:24.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:37:24.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.9:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:37:24.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 38.229.1.78:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:37:24.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 38.229.33.83:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
19.06.2017 12:38:22.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
19.06.2017 12:38:22.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
19.06.2017 12:38:22.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
19.06.2017 12:38:23.100 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: You appear to be running an altered version of Tor. This is potentially a problem. What changes does this altered version from dodgy Russian marketplaces make?